# innerhtml.replace not replacing all words in array javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that replaces a word with another.

For example if I have:

```
var rep = [['aa','b'],['bb','c']...['yy','z']];
var len = 26;

for(i = 0; i <len; i++){
  document.body.innerHTML=document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+rep[i][0]+"\\b","gi"),rep[i][1]);
}
```

...it only replaces the first few pairs of the array,but not the latter pairs.
For example if I have 
" aa is a bb is a yy",
it only changes to
"b is c is yy", "yy" is unchanged.
How do i make it so that it replaces ALL the words in the array?

Comment: In that example, shouldn't *all* the letters (eventually) change into z's? Anyway, what do you mean "some" letters "like" a to b? Does it do any other letters, or *only* a to b?

Comment: Your new wording still says "some" and "like", which is still a bit vague. Does it change anything other than "aa" to "b"? Maybe it would be best if you could do a simple demo at jsfiddle.net so that we can see the incorrect behaviour in action.

Comment: I don't know how jsfiddle works but I added an example. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the ECMA Script spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) `replace()` does not take an array as replacement argument, though a function is allowed. That function gets a variable count of arguments: *the matched substring*, *the groups (variable)*, *the offset index of the first match* and *the initial string*.

My approach uses one matcher and a matcher function that conditionally replaces the match with a replacement. The pair is picked from an object mapping search string to replacement.  If the search string is not found, the matched string is returned resulting is no change.

```
var replMap = {
        // specify search tokens as lowercase!
        xx: "A",
        yy: "B",
        zz: "C"
    },
    str = "xx is yy is zz";

str.replace(/\b([a-z]+)\b/gi, function(match, g1, offset, string) {
    // get replacement by matched group value, fall back to value
    return replMap[g1.toLowerCase()] || g1;
});
// > "A is B is C"
```

The `replMap` structure is used for convenience. I assume that it's possible to create it this way. If not, either the function can be changed (not provided in this answer) or the array of arrays can be converted to a map using `reduce()`:

```
var rep = [["xx", "AA"], ["yy", "BB"], ["zz", "CC"]],
    replMap = rep.reduce(function(map, arr) { map[arr[0]] = arr[1]; return map; }, {});
```

Further information on `replace()` with replacement function can be found at Mozilla developer network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 0):

Hummm your code seems to work Ô_o :

```js
var arr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');
var rep = arr.map(function(a, i) { 
  return [a+a,arr[i+1]];
});
var len = rep.length,
  str = document.body.innerHTML;

for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
  str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + rep[i][0]+"\\b","gi"), rep[i][1]);
}

document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<body>
  aa is a bb is a yy
</body>
```

Comment: it works when the array is short, but when it has 30+ items it doesn't anymore.

Comment: Hummm...  not sure if I truly understand your argument with "30+ items" there is 26 items in the current exemple. Could you provide more information to reproduce ?

Comment: using my current example, with 26 examples, let's say I add a few more to 30 items. only the first 10 or so words will get replaced, but the last few wouldn't change. It would work if the array has few items like 10, but not when it's a large number